# c# save-change string in code

Tags: c#, string, resources

Where i can save string , and when program run, user can change it -overrride. (not config file, i do not want that anybody can see what written).

Many thanks.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. What exactly are you trying to do? What string are you trying to save and what are you trying to override?

Comment: thank you for respones !
for example sql server name, and user can change it when program run, and when program start again it will connect to other sql server- that user write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Windows Application, your best bet is [isolated storage.](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/article.php/c4225/)

[Old Answer] 
In case you are using a web application:
If you want to do save the string till the user is logged in then you can store it in the Session state, if you want to store it for the lifetime of the web application  in IIS then you can use Application State

Of course you can store the same in a database if required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Settings (in Project Properties) to store USER and APPLICATION specific values. USER values can be changed and saved by the user at runtime and are stored in user's appdata directory (user.config) on the system whereas the APPLICATION values are stored in OUTPUTFILE.CONFIG file in the application directory.

You can encrypt these USER values before saving and decrypt after loading them. The values can accessed as: Properties.Settings.Default.SETTINGNAME

Also, if you want to do the reading and writing yourself, you can check the EncryptedXml class.

Comment: Tahnks you! and is it not possible to save read date in  EXE file yes ?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to update the EXE file itself. Office files such as DOC, XLS etc can keep Custom Properties using DSOFILE library but for EXEs I am not aware of any such utility

Answer (score 0):

You can encrypt string before saving to configuration to prevent user to read that string.

Comment: thanks , it is solution, but is it not possible save it in the EXE file?

Comment: You can try to store in dll using reflection emit, I don't think you can change exe that is executing... Isolated Storage is a way to store such data too, but it is not so secure too, so you should encrypt in this case too.